# $\sup_n \inf_{y \in X} (F(y) + n d(x,y))= F(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $F : X \rightarrow [0, +\infty)$ a lower semicontinuous function. Then
$$ \sup_n \inf_{y \in X} (F(y) + n d(x,y))= F(x). $$

Is this true?

Intuitively it works since the increasing distance increases the sum of the two functions everywhere except in $x$, but can't figure out how to prove it formally.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why was this downvoted?

Comment: What does convex mean in a general metric space?

Comment: @AhaanRungta: I have no idea why it is gathering downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\inf_{y \in \mathbb{R}} (f(y) + n d(x,y) ) \le f(x)$, we have $\sup_n \inf_{y \in \mathbb{R}} (f(y) + n d(x,y) ) \le f(x) $.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $f$ is lsc. at $x$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $d(x,y) < \delta$, then $f(y) \ge f(x) -\epsilon$. If we choose $n \ge \frac{f(x)}{\delta}$, then if $d(x,y) \ge \delta$, we have $f(y) + n d(x,y) \ge \frac{f(x)}{\delta} d(x,y)  \ge f(x)$. Hence
$\inf_{y \in \mathbb{R}} (f(y) + n d(x,y) ) \ge f(x) -\epsilon$ and hence
$\sup_n \inf_{y \in \mathbb{R}} (f(y) + n d(x,y) ) \ge f(x) -\epsilon$. Since
$\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we have the desired result.

Comment: I assumed $F \geq 0$ everywhere

Comment: @user102293: I missed that first time around. I have fixed it.

Comment: Always take an epsilon of room! Thanks ;)

Comment: Hard to escape fiddly $\epsilon$s with semi-continuity.